# could not compile `proc-macro2` (lib) due to 3 previous errors

Tags: ink, error

I run `cargo install  contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.23.0 --force --locked`  and then got an error, version of the `proc-macro2` library is incompatible with the `proc_macro` module I see that it is or does not meet a specific configuration or version requirement regarding `proc_macro2`.

What would be the reason?

Comment: what rust version are you using?

Comment: why v0.23.0? last is v0.33.0